# Magnto 2.3 Newsletter Queue not sending

Tags: cron, magento2.3, newsletter

The newsletter remain in the "not sent" state.
Cron Job is up and running and all mails work accordingly.
newsletter subscribtion mails are sent as well.

magento/var/log/exception.log shows this obscure error:

```
main.CRITICAL: Error when running a cron job {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0): Error when running a cron job at /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/module-cron/Observer/ProcessCronQueueObserver.php:327, Error(code: 0): Call to a member function appendChild() on null at /var/www/magento/vendor/pelago/emogrifier/src/Emogrifier.php:1419)"} []
```

Any hints to solve the problem?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness.
The Problem occured due to some bad templating. Emogrifier could not create working html/css code.
After clearing the queue at mysql-cli level with

```
DELETE FROM newsletter_queue WHERE queue_id = "{id}"
```

Mails are sent now..

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Magento 2.4
It seemed my newsletters weren't sending, but:

In my case, even though I set correct Time Zone in my Magento Configuration, my server was changing the time I entered to 6 hours ahead. My solution is to simply set queue time selector 6 hours sooner, and then it is sent. My cron tries sending newsletters in queue every 5 minutes. Yours is likely different.